# Увеличение картинки при наведении

Tags: css

По идеи работает, но тут вся соль в том что нужен прозрачный фон, я его поверх ставлю и из за этого не работает увеличение, как это можно обыграть?
вот

```css
.com-loop > h3 {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}

.com-loop > p {
  bottom: 10%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}

.com-loop img {
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.com-loop img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.t334__overlay {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 vtor-main">
<article >
<div class="col-md-12 no-pad">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">     
      <div class="com-loop">
 <img style="width:100%; margin:0; padding:0" src="https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3033-3537-4462-b861-376663666364/blob.png" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />


  <h3><span>Деловой центр</span></h3>
  <p>Аренда Продажа</p>
  </div>
            <div class="t334__overlay t334__animation_fast" style="background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.60), rgba(0,0,0,0.60)); background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.60), rgba(0,0,0,0.60)); background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.60), rgba(0,0,0,0.60)); background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.60), rgba(0,0,0,0.60));"></div>
      
                          
       
       
      </a>    </div>


</article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, подойдёт

```
pointer-events: none;
```